# Tooltip over cell. GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I use pure GWT. How i can implement dynamic different tooltips for every cell. Or if it hard to implement, how to implement different tooltip for eveery ROW? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do it have a look at a [very good example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/TablecellhovertooltipSmartGWT.htm) of it.

```
ListGridField nameField = new ListGridField("countryName", "Country");
ListGridField governmentField = new ListGridField("government", "Government", 120);
governmentField.setShowHover(true);
governmentField.setHoverCustomizer(new HoverCustomizer() {
    public String hoverHTML(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
        CountryRecord countryRecord = (CountryRecord) record;
        int governmentDesc = countryRecord.getGovernmentDesc();
        String[] governmentDescription = new String[]{
          //your data see link for more detail""
  };
        return governmentDescription[governmentDesc];
    }
});

countryGrid.setFields(countryCodeField, nameField, governmentField);
countryGrid.setCanResizeFields(true);
countryGrid.setData(CountryData.getRecords());
canvas.addChild(countryGrid);
```

Comment: I think this example can be applied only to Smart GWT. I need pure GWT example. thanks